# What will case "Can't access ViewModels from onDestroy" and how to solve it gracefully?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Some errors like

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {xxxxxx}:
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access ViewModels from
   onDestroy
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. This would include the complete Java stack trace associated with this exception, plus your code that is referenced in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the Android source code, it checks if the support FragmentManager is destroyed when trying to get a ViewModel.

Calling

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
```

will get to

```
private static HolderFragment findHolderFragment(FragmentManager manager) {
    if (manager.isDestroyed()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't access ViewModels from onDestroy");
    }
```

Which will throw the exception if the FragmentManager is destroyed. Take care when the get ViewModel code executes with respect to the app lifecycle.

To solve this, you can:

- check for getSupportFragmentManager().isDestroyed() before using the
  ViewModel
- surround with try catch and ignore if does not affect your normal
  flow